# ansible -how to pickup hostname and create self signed certificate

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-tower, ansible-galaxy

i have working command for creating self signed certificate for IHS server's .kdb file and i was trying to use the same command through ansible. Here my aim is that ansible should detect the hostname of application servers and should use that name for the "-dn" of the command.
Below is the working command

[root@myhost bin]# ./gskcmd -cert -create -db /opt/myapp/key.kdb -label IHS -expire 3650 -size 2048 -dn "CN=myserverFQDN" -default_cert yes -pw password

but below is my play and its giving syntax error

```
tasks:
  - name: get hostname
    shell: echo $HOSTNAME
    register: hostname

  - name: create self signed certificate for IHS
    command: /opt/myapp/bin/gskcmd -cert -create -db /opt/myapp/key.kdb -label IHS -expire 3650 -size 2048 -dn "CN={{ hostname}}" -default_cert yes -pw password
```

Comment: Actually posting the complete and error message (at a suitable debug level and preferably as code but even screenshot would help) is usually a good thing. - Is the hostname what you need (and not the FQDN)? Why don't you use `{{ ansible_hostname }}` instead of running a shell command to determine the hostname?

Comment: Thanks HBruijin, it helped me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to echo anything to "get" the hostname. It's already one of Ansible's gathered facts, `ansible_nodename`. You just need to use it.

```
    command: /opt/myapp/bin/gskcmd -cert -create -db /opt/myapp/key.kdb -label IHS -expire 3650 -size 2048 -dn "CN={{ansible_nodename}}" -default_cert yes -pw password
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may need to use one of the alternate facts, `ansible_hostname` or `inventory_hostname`.

These variables are set as follows:

- `inventory_hostname` is the hostname as it is set in your Ansible inventory. For example `www.internal-name.example`.
- `ansible_hostname` is the unqualified hostname as reported by the system. For example `www`.
- `ansible_nodename` is the fully qualified hostname as reported by the system. For example `www.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks Hello Michael.. It worked like a magic... Appreciated your help